# Hello, i need please that the day selcted automatic on the real day today and also i need that the previous days will be blocked to select

Tags: html, select, days, weekday

i need please that the day selcted automatic on the real day today and also i need that the previous days will be blocked to select.for example today is Wednesday, so i need that the selected day will be Wednesday and Tuesday, Monday and Sunday will be blocked.its html of course.

this is the whole html code:

```
<head>
<title>מסדר המשימות</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://finansita.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/luz.jpg" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-red-geometric-background_1055-3131.jpg');
    }

    img {
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

    h1{
         text-align: center;
         background-color:#e6e6ff;
         font-weight: bold;

    }

    div.form-group{
        font-size:110%;
        text-indent: 2.5px;
    }

    p.alert-info{
        text-indent: 2.5px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script>
    function number_of_tasks_selected(element) {

        var tasks_to_show = element.selectedIndex + 1;

        for (var line = 1; line <= tasks_to_show; line++) {
            var div = document.getElementById("task_" + line);
            div.classList.remove("hide");
        }

        for (var line = tasks_to_show + 1; line <= 10; line++) {
            var div = document.getElementById("task_" + line);
            div.classList.add("hide");
        }
    }

    function days_in_week(element) {

        var days_to_show = element.selectedIndex + 1;

        for (var line = 1; days_to_show; line++) {
            var div = document.getElementById("day_" + line);
            div.classList.remove("hide");
        }

        for (var line = days_to_show + 1; line <= 10; line++) {
            var div = document.getElementById("day_" + line);
            div.classList.add("hide");
        }

        var today = new Date(); var day = today.getDay(); document.getElementById("mySelect").options.namedItem(day).selected = true;
    }

    function validateForm() {
        var element = document.getElementById("number_of_tasks");
        var tasks = element.selectedIndex + 1;

        for (var line = 1; line <= tasks; line++) {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["task_name_" + line].value;

            if (x == "") {
                alert("שכחת להזין את שם המשימה במשימה מספר: " + line);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    function resetForm() {
        for (var line = 1; line <= 10; line++) {
            document.forms["myForm"]["task_name_" + line].value = "";
        }
    }

    function loadForm() {
        var element = document.getElementById("number_of_tasks");
        number_of_tasks_selected(element);
    }

</script>
<div class="container well">

    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;">מסדר המשימות היומי שלכם</h1>

    <h3 style="font-family:'Helvetica';">
        <b>
            מתקשים לארגן את יומכם בצורה נבונה? הטילו עליכם מטלות רבות? המון שיעורי בית? הגעתם למקום הנכון!

            <br />
            ״מסדר המשימות״ הוא כלי נהדר שבו תוכלו להשתמש על מנת לארגן את יומכם בצורה הטובה ביותר.<br/>
            <br />
            על פי רמת הדחיפות ודרגת הקושי שתזינו למערכת
            – ״מסדר המשימות״ יוכל לארגן בעבורכם את סדר היום<br /> ולתת לכל משימה ומשימה זמן מוקצב כך שתוכלו להספיק הכול כבר באותו היום!<br/>
        </br>
    </h3>


    <br/>
    <img src="http://finansita.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/luz.jpg" alt="tasks" width="570" height="400">
    <img src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/4/4d/Organize-Your-Day-Step-6-Version-2.jpg/aid282411-v4-900px-Organize-Your-Day-Step-6-Version-2.jpg" alt="tasks" width="550" height="400">


        <h4>
                <br />
                כדי להתחיל בסידור ובארגון יומכם עקבו אחר ההוראות:
        </h4>

    <div>
        <form action="schedule.jsp" method="post" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm" onreset="resetForm()" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
            <div>
                <p class="alert alert-success">
                    <b>choose day:</b>
                    <select class="form-control" id="" name="days_in_week" onchange="days_in_week(this)">
                        <option value="1">sunday</option>
                        <option value="2">monday</option>
                        <option value="3" >Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="5">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="6">Friday</option>
                        <option value="7">Saturday</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p class="alert alert-success">
                    <b>בחר במספר המשימות הדרוש:</b>
                    <select class="form-control" id="number_of_tasks" name="number_of_tasks" onchange="number_of_tasks_selected(this)">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p class="alert alert-success">
                    <b>הקש זמן עבודה פנוי בשעות</b>
                    (ספרות בלבד):
                    <input type="number" value="5" class="form-control" name="free_hours" max="16">
                </p> 

            </div>
            <h3 style="font-family:'Helvetica';"><br /> רשימת משימות:</h3>

            <div id="task_1" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_1">משימה 1:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_1" id="task_name_1"  maxlength="25" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_1">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_1" id="priority_1">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_1">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_1" id="diff_1">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_2" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_2">משימה 2:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_2" id="task_name_2"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_2">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_2" id="priority_2">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_2">דרגת קושי</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_2" id="diff_2">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_3" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_3">משימה 3:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_3"  id="task_name_3"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_3">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_3" id="priority_3">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_3">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_3" id="diff_3">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="task_4" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_4">משימה 4:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_4"  id="task_name_4"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_4">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_4" id="priority_4">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_4">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_4" id="diff_4">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_5" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_5">משימה 5:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_5"  id="task_name_5"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_5">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_5" id="priority_5">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_5">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_5" id="diff_5">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_6" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_6">משימה 6:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_6"  id="task_name_6"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_6">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_6" id="priority_6">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_6">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_6" id="diff_6">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_7" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_7">משימה 7:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_7"  id="task_name_7"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_7">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_7" id="priority_7">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_7">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_7" id="diff_7">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_8" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_8">משימה 8:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_8"  id="task_name_8"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_8">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_8" id="priority_8">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_8">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_8" id="diff_8">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_9" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_9">משימה 9:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_9"  id="task_name_9"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_9">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_9" id="priority_9">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_9">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_9" id="diff_9">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="task_10" class="alert alert-info">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_name_10">משימה 10:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name_10"  id="task_name_10"  maxlength="25">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="priority_10">דחיפות</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="priority_10" id="priority_10">
                        <option value="1" selected>לא דחוף</option>
                        <option value="2">רגיל</option>
                        <option value="3">דחוף</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="diff_10">דרגת קושי</label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="diff_10" id="diff_10">
                        <option value="1" selected>קל</option>
                        <option value="2">בינוני</option>
                        <option value="3">קשה</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!--<input type="reset" value="נקה טופס">
    <input type="submit" value="צור לוח זמנים">-->


            <style>
                .button {
                    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
                    border:none;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 13px 32px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 17px;
                    margin: 4px 2px;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
                    transition-duration: 0.4s;
                    font-weight:bold;

                }

                .button1:hover {
                    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
                }

                .button2:hover {
                    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
                }
            </style>

                <button class="button button1" type="reset" value="נקה טופס">נקה טופס</button>
                <button class="button button2" type="submit" value="צור לוח זמנים">צור לוח זמנים</button>



            </form>
    </div>
    <hr />

</div>
```

Comment: This question could be improved by including the entire html document, or creating a jsfiddle example that can be executed and tested.

Comment: i added the full code

Answer (score 0):

add this before"select":

```
 <script> 
 var today=new Date(); var day= today.getDay();
 document.getElementById("mySelect").options.namedItem(day).selected =true; 
</script>
```